# Xrefresh alternative

Tags: css, firefox, netbeans, workflow, firebug

i am using Netbeans PHP + Firefox 4 on Windows for my web development.

I've used a common firebug extension called Xrefresh. It was automaticlly refreshing my opened firefox tab everytime change in my projects directory occured, so pressing ctrl+s in netbeans was triggering auto-refresh in the browser. Very comfort way to work with css, almost live preview.

But now since new Firefox and Firebug versions Xrefresh doesn't work anymore and the question is - are therey any good alternatives, or does someone know how to configure Xrefresh now?
Without live preview my development is somehow slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an automatic refresh-on-change tool for IE.  It's called ReloadIt, and is available at http://reloadit.codeplex.com . Free.

Not an add-on to IE, but more of an "adjunct".  It does not change the IE install, does not install a BHO or anything like that.  So very low-impact installation.

You choose a URL that you'd like to auto-reload, and specify one or more directory paths to monitor for changes.  Press F12 to start monitoring.

[image]

After you set it, minimize it.  Then edit your content files. When you save, the page gets reloaded.  like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/NV/auto_update_stylesheets

This could help you. It refreshes the page via ajax on css save.

Comment: It is a 404. The idea is cool, but i can't google any css reload on change bookmarlet. Either they reload every 1-2 seconds or when i click... and what i want - is to reload on change.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to keep using xrefresh up until Firefox 9 however I'm not having any luck with version 10.

I've now switched to [livereload](http://livereload.com/), they've had a decent Mac version out for a while and a very experimental Windows version has recently been released.