# Is there a way to get IE to automatically reload a tab when the content is updated?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I learned of a nifty tool for Mac devs (I guess) - called LiveReload.  It reloads a web page in Safari when a change is detected in one of a specified set of files.

I develop on Windows.  Is there a similar tool for Windows?  something that will automatically reload a page in IE, when necessary?  It would save time flipping between the editor and the browser during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a tool called [ReloadIt](http://reloadit.codeplex.com) that does this.

Configure the tool to "watch" one or more directories, and if any file changes in any of those directories, the tool will reload a tab in IE.  It's like an automatic, intelligent F5. Good for eliminating all the context switching between editor and web page.

If you have dual monitors, you can edit in one screen, and see the changes on the other, without flipping windows.

Here's an animation of an editing session in emacs.  In the background, an IE tab displays a bar chart generated with the flot javascript library.  When the Javascript module is saved in the editor, the page showing the chart automatically reloads.

[image]

The tool is free.

Configuration is a one-time thing. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: is there anything similar in firefox?

Comment: used to be a FF extension, I think called xrefresh?  Not sure of its current status.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031109